# HTTPS4 Component configuration for using SSLcontext with keystore file, stil unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-camel

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource(getConfigDir() + keystore); 
    ksp.setPassword("changeit");
    TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    tmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setTrustManagers(tmp);
    HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
    httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);

    from("timer://timer1?fixedRate=true&period=5000")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
    .to(getSource())
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "File ${file:name} inProgress")

    .to(getDestination()).process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            String currentFileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME);
            Long currentFileSize = (Long) exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_LENGTH);

            feedLogger.log(Level.INFO, currentFileName + " processed");
            feedLogger.log(Level.INFO, currentFileName + " size: " + currentFileSize + " Bytes");
        }
    }).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "File ${file:name} processed").setId(getId());
}
```

my source , lets say https:https://www.blabla.org and I'm using HTTP4 as a componenet**but still give me: unable to find valid certification path to requested target **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found it , I was trapped by HonyPot which was in our server and dosen't recogniz the HTTP4 for passing by the Proxy so all I need to append that Scheme to my Endpoint...`proxyAuthHost=****&proxyAuthPort=80&proxyAuthScheme=http4`